Jenkins as a Docker Container loses all pipelines on docker-compose up?
I am running a Jenkins container on a Linux VM. I had some pipelines on the Jenkins UI, and I was working with them. Since we made use of a docker-compose file for setting up the container, I just did a docker compose down, made the changes and started the container again docker compose up -d. I expected the pipelines that I was working on to be persistent, but the Jenkins instance was just empty.
I mounted the previous workspace as well. Still the previous pipelines do not show up.
Am I missing something here?
version: "3"
services:
  jenkins:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-Jenkins
    ports:
      - 8081:8080
      - 5900:5900
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/docker/volumes/jenkins_compose_jenkins_home/_data/:/var/jenkins_home #added after changes to mount the workspace
#      - jenkins_home/:/var/jenkins_home   #This was previously present
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    networks:
      - mynetwork
#volumes:
# jenkins_home:

networks:
  mynetwork:


I can still see all the builds under /_data/workspace

Sounds like you didn't configure any volume to persist data. Show us the docker-compose.yml.

I have added it now @KlausD.

I am pretty sure that this line isn't configured correctly - jenkins_home/:/var/jenkins_home, you need to ditch the / after jenkins_home, I run a very similar compose file and that's the main difference I could see.
Here's your compose file fixed up a bit:
version: "3"
services:
  jenkins:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-Jenkins
    ports:
      - 8081:8080
      - 5900:5900
    volumes:
      - jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    networks:
      - mynetwork

volumes:
  jenkins-data:

networks:
  mynetwork:

I also got rid of the first volume mount you're trying to do, it doesn't seem relevant to me, looks like you were trying to troubleshoot the volume issue you're having. The compose file I provided should work for you, let me know if it doesn't. I've changed jenkins_home to jenkins-data so it doesn't conflict with your existing volumes, if any.
